# wget stops downloading: Cannot write to `-' (success)

Tags: centos, dropbox, http, wget

Please have in mind that I don't know anything about servers, nor any of its vocabulary, I am a simple web coder, trying to figure my way on the universe.

I'm trying to link dropbox on my server, I am using this line of code:

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
```

When I run it, it shows me the error:

> ```
> Cannot write to `-' (Success).
> ```

I am puzzled and I don't know what to do. My CentOS is 64 bit, version 6.5.

Comment: Do you have write permissions to the **~** directory? Does **touch foo** give you an error?

Comment: as I've said, I don't know anything about servers, can you please be more specific?

Comment: Learing how CentOS works and specifically how [file permissions work](http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/) would be a good starting point. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `-` as the parameter of the option `-O` it represent the standard output.

You are using a pipeline so both commands are executed in parallel and the standard input of the `tar` command is bound to the standard output of the `wget` command.

The `tar` command is breaking the pipeline so `wget` can not write to standard output.

When this happens, check the error messages before `Cannot write to (backtick)- (Success)`. You might see there the cause of the error of the second command.

Answer (score 1):

First of a brief breakdown of the command you're using.

`cd ~` - will descend you to your "home" directory (~ is a variable)

`wget -O` - will download the file

`tar -zxf` - will unpack downloaded file

Try the step-by-step approach. In terminal type following:

- 1. `cd ~` and type `pwd` (your location should be something like
     /home/username)
- 2. `wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-2.10.52.tar.gz`
     (Notice I included the full path to the file, unlike yours in the
     description)
- 3. `tar xzf dropbox-lnx.x86_64-2.10.52.tar.gz`

TIP: To test if you have write permissions on a specific folder, simply "`cd`" to that folder and type: "`touch test`". If you have write permissions it should create an empty file called test in that folder

Hope this helps

Cheers!
Deeh